# Are integro-differential equations considered dynamical systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, integro-differential-equations

A definition of the dynamical system is that:

> $\phi:R \times E \to E$ is a dynamical system where $\phi \in C^1$,
>   $E$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if $\phi_t(x) = \phi(t,x)$,
>   then $\phi_0(x) = x$ for all $x \in E$ and $\phi_t \circ \phi_s(x) =
>  \phi_{t+s}(x) $ for all $s,t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in E$ (Perko)

**For instance, given**: $$\dot x = Ax$$
$$x(0) = x_0$$

$\phi(t,x) = \exp(At)x_o$ defines a dynamical system on $\mathbb{R}^n$

**Does the solution to an integro-differential equation of the form**

$$\dot x = \int^t_0 f(x(s)) ds$$
$$x(0) = x_0$$

violate the definition of a dynamical system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no; it does not violate the definition of a dynamical system.

You can define a typical dynamical system for the system
$$\dot{x}=\int_0^t{f(x(s))ds}$$
by increasing the order of the state vector. Specifically, if we define the extra state 
$$\xi:=\int_0^t{f(x(s))ds}$$
then we have the augmented state vector $x_{ag}:=[\matrix{x^T & \xi^T}]^T$ with a the classical form
$$\dot{x}_{ag}=f_{ag}(x_{ag}):=\left[\matrix{\xi \\f(x)}\right]$$
and initial condition $x_{ag}(0)=[\matrix{x_0 & 0}]^T$. Then it is standard to define the dynamical system for the new autonomous ODE system assuming locally Lipschitz property for $f$ by using Picard iteration.